# How to solve "Target runtime caf.default.runtime is not defined." error in Designer

Tags: webmethods

I had a very strange error today, that Designer (Eclipse) shown:

> Target runtime caf.default.runtime is not defined.

in Problem view for CAF project

[image: Target runtime caf.default.runtime is not defined.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be easily fixed by invoking CAF Tools > Repair CAF Project from context menu (right click) on a project.

[image: CAF Tools > Repair CAF Project]